# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS dock's “Show Applications” only showing first page

Tags: unity, 20.04, dock

The Ubuntu 20.04 LTS dock's “Show Applications” is only showing the first page of installed applications. The "Frequent" selection is working fine but when "All" is selected the page won't scroll down and the 'page select' buttons at right of screen also fail to change the page. Page down and page up keys are also not changing the "Show Applications" pages.
I can search for the application via the search bar at top of page but the easy access of the scrolling page layout is a feature that seems a bit busted in 20.04.

I am guessing this is one of those little hiccups that will be dealt with over time but thought best to mention it in case someone has a fix.
Have a nice day.

Comment: Does it happen on a new account with default settings also?

Comment: i set up a new account and yes it happened with that user also. Wierd but hey such is life

Comment: At least you know it is not a user configuration issue. Next: is this an updated system or a fresh install?

Comment: Fresh install.I find 20.04 really good. Happy to hear it isn't a widespread issue and have a gut feeling it'll magically be working after some future update settles into the system :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it happens when your dock is displayed on the left side of the screen. It's a bug as far as I know.

There are three workarounds:

1. If you use a dual-screen setup, try detaching and reattaching the secondary screen.
2. Go to **Settings >> Appearance >> Position on Screen - *Right or Bottom***

   Changing dock position solves the issue somehow.
3. Running this command in your terminal will help you solve it if you like the dock to be on the left side only:

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock extend-height false
   ```

Comment: Thank you. I do have a dual-screen setup and do prefer the dock on the left side. The gsettings fix you suggested worked for me.

Comment: @Rhys - Then please accept and upvote the answer to indicate that the solution worked for you. The `gsettings` command seems to have helped a number of other people too.